# Trying to get app to auto fetch from API on POST

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, get, crud

Basically I'm working on creating a ToDo app with CRUD operations, however, when I POST or DELETE a document from MongoDB, I'd like my hook to auto fetch the results. I can feel that this is a simple fix and I've tried some weird things including `useCallback` but nothing seems to work. Here's my hook:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAPI = () => {
  const backendURL = '<InsertURL>.com/api/todos';
  const [retrievedData, setRetrievedData] = useState([]);

  //sends todo to database
  const postToDo = useCallback(async (newToDo) => {
    await axios
      .post(backendURL, newToDo)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  }, []);

  //deletes a todo from the database
  const deleteToDo = async (todo) => {
    console.log(todo);
    await axios
      .delete(backendURL, todo)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };

  //gets todos from database
  useEffect(() => {
    const getToDos = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(backendURL)
        .then((fetchedData) => {
          setRetrievedData(fetchedData.data.todos);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
    };
    getToDos();
  }, [postToDo]);

  return { retrievedData, postToDo, deleteToDo };
};
```

Basically, I want `postToDo` to be called and then for `getToDos` to execute immediately afterwards without having to refresh the page. I'll want to use this same technique to with `deleteToDo`.

Why `useCallback`? Because ESlinter told me to do it if I put `postToDo` in `getToDos` dependency. I thought if I put `postToDo` in the array it would update when the function was called, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'm also worried about trying too many weird things because I added 30+ documents to my database on accident when it auto executed a bunch of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstracting away your React hooks, you can sequence asynchronous actions by using the `.then` promise syntax (as one example):

```
const postToDos = async (newToDo) => {
    await axios
      .post(backendURL, newToDo)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
}

const getToDos = async () => {
      await axios.get(backendURL)
}

postToDos(newToDo).then(getToDos).then(fetchedData => {
    setRetrievedData(fetchedData.data.todos)
})
```

Or, you can combine the async/await syntax into a single function

```
const postToDos = async (newToDo) => {
    await axios
      .post(backendURL, newToDo)
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
}

const getToDos = async () => {
      await axios.get(backendURL)
}

const postAndGetToDos = async (newToDo) => {
    await postToDo(newToDo)
    var fetchedData = await getToDos()
    setRetrievedData(fetchedData.data.todos)
}

postAndGetToDos({/*new toDo object*/)
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion in 2 separate ways and got similar results.
First, I tried 
.then(getToDos).catch(err.....) which kept sending 
Network Error net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
Then I tried just calling getToDos after with similar results.
I'll try the third one but it'll take me a second

Comment: Ok, so I took the useEffect out of the hook and called it in the ToDo component that was using the functions, then passed the getToDos function from the hook and to the component and am using around my app to be called when necessary. The only problem is the dependency array wants getToDos in it which causes it to fire every render cycle and gives me the network err (because chrome is handling too many requests at once)

Comment: On a final note, I used async await in my component and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you just want to fetch the data back when you delete a post, right?

I think, you need to trigger your useEffect properly.

You first need to modify an Array that contains todo items such that you must remove the item which you intend to remove from the backend in `deleteToDo` and have it passed in `useEffect`.

```
 //gets todos from database
  useEffect(() => {
    const getToDos = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(backendURL)
        .then((fetchedData) => {
          setRetrievedData(fetchedData.data.todos);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
    };
    getToDos();
  }, [postToDo, <TodoArray>]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's the exact sort of tactic I was trying to move away from to prevent using extra state I didn't need. If you read the above reply's comments, you'll see I took away the useEffect and passed the getToDos function to the component I need them and then handle the calls there.